# rails howto use environment constant in models and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have my constants initialized in environment.rb like this :

```
 Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...
  MAX_BID = 10
 end
```

i would like to use this constant in my models and views,what is the correct syntax?
if a use it a model its says

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant User::MAX_BID
```

i understand that it is looking for the constant inside the model , how can i tell explicitly that this constant is in the environment?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use an initializer with all of your constants in `/config/initializers/constants.rb`

```
MAX_BID = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Pull it outside the `config` block.

So do this instead:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...
end

MAX_BID = 10
```

Comment: Then you have other issues... Did you restart the app after making the change to `environment.rb`? How are you referencing the constant (the actual line of code)? You could also try `::MAX_BID`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
Rails::MAX_BID
```